# How to insert images and data into mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a trouble to saving data into the database. My connection details and sql insert query everything is correct and image is also uploading to folder but I do not know why data along with image  is not saving into an database when i hit upload button.Can anyone help me please?

My php code

```
<?php 


include('server.php');
$userID = 1;

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   $userName =  $_SESSION['username'];
   $queryID = "SELECT id from users WHERE username = '$userName'";
   $resultID = $db->query($queryID);
   $row=$resultID->fetch_assoc();
   $userID = $row['id'];


}


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
     $target = "images/".basename($image);

    $eventName = $_POST['eventName'];
    $eventDetail = $_POST['eventDetail'];
    $eventDate = $_POST['eventDate'];
    $eventTime = $_POST['eventTime'];


    $queryImage = "INSERT INTO event_detail(eventName,eventDetails,eventDate,eventTime,imagePath,userID) VALUES('$eventName','$eventDetail','$eventDate','$eventTime','$image','$userID')";

    mysqli_query($db,$queryImage);


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$target))
    {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "There is problem";

    }

}




?>

html 
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="eventName">Event Name:<label> 
<input type="text" id="eventName" name="eventName" ><br><br>
<label for="eventDetail">Event Detail:<label> 
<textarea id="eventDetail" name="eventDetail" ></textarea><br><br>
<label for="eventDate">Event Date:<label> 
<input type="text" id="eventDate" name="eventDate" ><br><br>
<label for="eventTime">Event Time:<label> 
<input type="text" id="eventTime" name="eventTime" ><br><br>
<input type="file" id="image" name="image"><br><br> 
<button  type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to echo your $msg. What is getting echoed?

Comment: Yes I did and I get error msg because I have set error in else statement..

Comment: You are setting $msg dependent on whether moving the uploaded file succeeded, this has nothing to do with whether your database query succeeded or not here.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
$queryImage = "INSERT INTO event_detail(eventName,eventDetails,eventDate,eventTime,imagePath,userID) VALUES ('$eventName','$eventDetail','$eventDate','$eventTime','$image','$userID')";
```

to

```
$queryImage = "INSERT INTO event_detail(eventName,eventDetails,eventDate,eventTime,imagePath,userID) VALUES ($eventName,$eventDetail,$eventDate,$eventTime,$image,$userID)";
```

Comment: Your suggestion will not work. String values should be escaped, also it's bad idea to generate sql insert, you should use param bindings